# Add binary to Applications Menu

Tags: 20.04, appmenu, binary

Is it possible to add a binary to the applications menu in Ubuntu 20.04.2? I have tried the following `.desktop` file for Filezilla which I extracted from `FileZilla_3.55.1_x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.bz2`:

```
Path=/home/user/Programs/FileZilla_3.55.1_x86_64-linux-gnu/FileZilla3/bin/
Exec=filezilla
Name=AppImageLauncher
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/user/Programs/FileZilla_3.55.1_x86_64-linux-gnu/FileZilla3/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/filezilla.png
```

I have used this approach for AppImages for which it works. Is there a way to do same for a binary?

Comment: Too complicated. Will have problem with updates Do you consider [FlatPak as alternative](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.filezillaproject.Filezilla)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

▶ You can add any executable to the applications menu, be it a binary or any script, as long as it is executable.

On the `Exec=` line, you need to specify a valid executable:

- If the executable resides in your search PATH (use `echo $PATH` to see all directories that are searched for executables), then you can simply specify the name of the executable file.
- If it resides elsewhere, you need to provide the full pathname to the executable, e.g. `/home/user/Programs/FileZilla_3.55.1_x86_64-linux-gnu/FileZilla3/bin/filezilla`.

▶ In order to see your application in the application menu, it must reside in one of the dedicated folder (use `echo $XDG_DATA_DIRS` to see them - add to each path `/applications` to obtain the actual folder). For your custom application, place it in `.local/share/applications` if you are the only user that needs to use the applications. Otherwise, put it in `/usr/local/share/applications`. You may need to create these folders if they are not present on your system.